# find all img tags inside html and move all to a certain div by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, image, appendto, detach

I have HTML code that contains images. 
Now, I try to find all images inside this html and move them to another div

This is HTML code

```
<div class="gallery slider" data-autoplay="true" data-autoheight="true">
  <figure>
    <div><img src="http://localhost/cms/source/41d78c1785d38ec8086941cf55971aef.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </figure>
</div><!-- gallery -->
<div id="trip-body">
    <img src="http://localhost/cms//source/img-09.jpg" alt="img-09">
</div>
```

and this is my Jquery

```
$('#trip-body').each(function () {
    var tripBody  = $(this);
    var tripImage = $(tripBody).find('img');

    $(tripImage).detach().appendTo('.post-area .slider figure');
});
```

but it doesn't work!

Comment: What doesn't work? Does anything happen? Do you get any errors in the developer console?

Comment: i suppose you have only one `#trip-body`, if so you don't need `.each()` for it?

Comment: id's should be unique. Using `.each` with an id selector will only work for the first element with that id on the page (unless you change it to `[id='#trip-body']` or something)

Comment: Change `id="trip-body"` to `class="trip-body"`.

Comment: @ajshort nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
$('#trip-body img').each(function () {
    $(this).detach().appendTo('.slider > figure');
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bxcf4mkL/)

Comment: Thank you for your replay, now it working successfully.